# Identifying JSON subtyping in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, polymorphism

If I have a parent and a child typescript objects:

```
class Parent {
    private parentField: string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    private childField: string;
}
```

Now I receive via a rest service a list of json objects of both types.

Normally when I receive a json object I just map it to a typescript object by copying all attributes. But in this case it is not that straightforward because I don't know which object I am dealing with (it can be Parent or Child)

What is the best way to map json type and subtypes into typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you receive a json it does **not** contain object of the types your posted. What you have are classes, and jsons has objects.
If you want to type what you get from json then:

```
interface Parent {
    parentField: string;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
    childField: string;
}
```

And then this is fine:

```
let json = { parent: { parentField: "a" }, child: { parentField: "a", childField: "b" } };
let parent: Parent = json.parent;
let child: Child = json.child;
```

If you're using classes then you need:

```
let parent = Object.assign(new Parent(), json.parent);
let child = Object.assign(new Child(), json.child);
```

To tell the difference use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isChild(obj: any): obj is Child {
    return obj.childField != null;
}

if (isChild(json.obj)) {
    // json obj is child
} else {
    // json obj is parent
}
```

Comment: In this usecase you actually know what you are receiving. I ask for a more general way to do it, since I am receiving a list of objects and not the objects by their own

Comment: @iberbeu why do you need a more general way? Can't you just call `isChild()` for each object in the array?

Comment: The type guard is a runtime check to differentiate between the types, it also tells the compiler that the object is of a certain type. What can be more general than that?

Comment: ok. I guess it could work. Anyway `obj.childField != null;` is not right. If that attribute is null because it hasn't got any value then isChild will be false which is not right. Shouldn't it be `obj.childField !== undefined;` since undefined is not a json value?

Comment: If you allow for a child to have `null` for `childField` then yeah, you need to check for `undefined`